# team foundation server 2012 restore

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am trying to restore a Team Foundation Server database to another server.

The Original server was a Team Foundation server express 2012 install.

Steps so far

- Created backup of all the databases using SQL management studio
  i.e. TFS_defaultCollection,TFS_Configuration, Tfs_Company1, TFS_Company2.
- Installed TFS Express 2012 on another server
- Restored all the SQL Server database's to the new server
  I get an error the SQL instance is missing.

Is there any way to restore the TFS databases to the new server.

or 
 is there any way to extract the project data from the databases.

Comment: What is the **precise** error you get, and when do you get it? Did you read and follow the documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869(v=vs.110).aspx?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have created the SQL instance in SQL server.

Based on your description your backup should be executed manually. So,to restore data for Team Foundation to a different server or instance, you must complete the procedures that your deployment topology requires the sequence mentioned in below link:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/backup/restore-data-different-instance#back-up-data

Recommend you follow the steps in [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Prepare) provided by Daniel to backup and restore the database from TFS Administrtion Console, it's more convenient than manually backup.